# Slice pandas series with elements not in the index

Tags: python, pandas, series, slice

I have a pandas series indexed by tuples, like this:

```
from pandas import Series
s = Series({(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 2, (0, 3): 3, (1, 0): 1, (1, 2): 4, (3, 0): 5})
```

I want to slice such a series by using indexes that are also tuples (using lexicographic ordering), but not necessarily in the index. Slicing seems to work when I pass an index that is on the series:

```
s[:(1,0)]
(0, 0)    1
(0, 1)    2
(0, 3)    3
(1, 0)    1
dtype: int64
```

but if I try slicing by an index which is not on the series there is an error:

```
s[:(1,1)]
...
ValueError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 0 was passed
```

Ideally I'd like to get the series elements indexed by (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 0), similar to what happens when slicing using dates in TimeSeries. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works if you have a MultiIndex rather than an index of tuples:

```
In [11]: s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.index)

In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
0  0    1
   1    2
   3    3
1  0    1
   2    4
3  0    5
dtype: int64

In [13]: s[:(1,1)]
Out[13]: 
0  0    1
   1    2
   3    3
1  0    1
dtype: int64
```

*In a previous edit I had suggested this could be [a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4443), and had created an awful hack...*